# PL/SQL DEVELOPER 10.2 create triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace trigger TDB_TRIGGER1
   before insert on KTOVOT
   for each row
declare
begin
   insert into TEMPORARY_DATA(MIS_ZEHUT,TA_RISHUM, SHEM_TAVLA)
   values(:new.id, sysdate, user_tables.table_name);
end TDB_TRIGGER1
```

I get this error:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

What I want to do here is to write into table:

```
TEMPORARY_DATA mis_zehut, ta_rishum, user_tables.table_name
```

I want to write the table name `ktovot` to the third  field of table `TEMPORARY_DATA` with no success.

If I do it hardcoded it will work:

```
values(:new.id, sysdate, 'ktovot' );
```

Comment: What's the problem with hardcoding it exactly? You need it in the trigger definition anyway.

Comment: You can't reference a column in this way; if you want to select data from a table you need to actually select data from the table... As mat says though, there's no need in this situation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered in the question.

Comment: @BobJarvis - The table name on which the trigger is defined is not *directly* available to the code.  But there are ways.

Comment: but without use functions,  i waana use constant words like: sysdate

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL does not support reflection - or rather it supports an extremely limited level of reflection. Nothing like Java.  But we can find out the name of the *current program unit* using the `$$PLSQL_UNIT` inquiry directive.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS294).

Triggers are program units, so we can find out the name of the currently executing trigger.  And with that piece of information we can look up the name of the table which owns the trigger:

```
create or replace function get_table_name
    ( i_trigger_name in varchar2)
    return varchar2
is
    return_value varchar2(30);
begin
    select table_name
    into return_value
    from user_triggers
    where trigger_name = i_trigger_name;
    return return_value;
end;
/
```

So, here is a journal table:

```
create table jrnl1 (id number
                     , action varchar2(20)
                     , ts timestamp
                     , table_name varchar2(30));
```

Here is a trigger to populate that journal, getting the table name dynamically:

```
create or replace trigger t23_trg
    before insert on t23 for each row
begin
    insert into jrnl1 values 
        (:new.id
         , 'INSERT'
         , systimestamp
         , get_table_name($$PLSQL_UNIT));
end;
/
```

And here is the proof of the pudding:

```
SQL> select * from jrnl1;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into t23 values ('TEST', 42);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from jrnl1;

        ID ACTION   TS                           TABLE_NAME
---------- -------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------
        42 INSERT   17-AUG-14 10.14.30.688672 AM T23

SQL>
```

I'm afraid it's not the elegant solution you might have hoped for.  And in fact, given that you have to write a separate trigger for each table I'm not sure it saves you much in the way of hard-coding.

But I think it makes an interesting toy which serves to illustrate how PL/SQL works.

Comment: +1 - `$$PLSQL_UNIT` is something I'd forgotten about. While this is an interesting way to do what OP requested, for my money this obfuscates the intent of the code and isn't something I'd recommend doing. But it's interesting nonetheless. :-)